# How do I get airflow to work with SQLalchemy 2.0.2 when it has a 1.4.48 version dependency?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

I have some problems in my project: I use SQLalchemy 2.0.2 in modules for working with the database however i try to use Apache Airflow 2.6.1 which has sqlalchemy 1.4.48 dependencies. After I run the code, the interpreter either does not work correctly with the database functions (if sqlalchemy 1.4.48 is installed), or it throws an exception(if version is 2.0) like:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'encoding' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/QueuePool/Engine
```

Step by step:

1. I install sqlalchemy(2.0) into a clean virtual environment on my computer with Windows OS.
2. Install apache-airflow with next command

```
pip install "apache-airflow[postgres]==2.6.1" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.1/constraints-3.9.txt"
```

3. Then i tried to start the code or use
   `pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy==2.0`  and then start the code.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The [airflow documentation](https://github.com/apache/airflow#approach-to-dependencies-of-airflow) has a good description of this situation, but I have not been able to figure out how to solve this problem.

I tried to uninstall SQLalchemy and apache-airflow and then tried to install with constrain. Tried to change some settings in airflow.cfg

Comment: Do you need to run airflow and your task(s) in the same python environment?

Comment: @JonSG, No, it will be running in the wsl, in another environments. I just placing dags in the windows dir, with my project

Comment: Yes, but conceptually you could run airflow in one python virtual env while the dags execute is a second virtual env right?

Comment: @JonSG, Yes. I also tried to install another env only for dags, but I don't understand how to import my modules in another env. I mean how import modules when it has another dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`PythonVirtualEnvOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator) ?

It will allow you to install the library at runtime so you don't need to make changes on the server just for one job.

To run a function called `my_callable`, simply use the following:

```py
my_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id="my_task ",
        requirements="sqlalchemy==2.0",
        python_callable=my_callable,
    )
```

Since the task runs in a virtual environment, it shouldn't be limited by Airflow dependencies.